# Instrumenting APK unsuccessfull in Cloud monkey

Tags: android, testing, mobile, automation

When trying to instrument APK it shows Instrumenting APK unsuccessful. Error instrumenting APK. When the emulator was opened before instrumenting in console it showed "Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer." 
After instrumentation it showed error with message
[image: Error message shown]

This is message shown in console

```
System.getProperty("java.home") = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
Instrumenting C:\Users\dinu\Desktop\EventManagement\CellStash.apk using C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tools_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107139\tools\mtagent\monkeytalk-agent.jar

Unpacking tools into C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tools_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107139\tools

Analyzing package Step 1 of 2

Unbundle started in C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1

Unbundle completed with exit code 0

Unbundle output:
I: Baksmaling...
I: Loading resource table...
I: Loaded.
I: Decoding AndroidManifest.xml with resources...
I: Loading resource table from file: C:\Users\dinu\apktool\framework\1.apk
I: Loaded.
I: Regular manifest package...
I: Decoding file-resources...
S: Could not decode file, replacing by FALSE value: drawable/popup.9.png
S: Could not decode file, replacing by FALSE value: drawable-mdpi/popup_bg.9.png
S: Could not decode file, replacing by FALSE value: drawable/action_item_selected.9.png
I: Decoding values */* XMLs...
I: Done.
I: Copying assets and libs...


Generated project directory: CellStash

AndroidTarget was no defined, obtaining last android target installed

androidTarget= android-19

Analyzing package Step 2 of 2

Dex started: C:\Users\dinu\Desktop\EventManagement\CellStash.apk

Dex completed with exit code 0

Dex output: dex2jar C:\Users\dinu\Desktop\EventManagement\CellStash.apk -> CellStash-dex2jar.jar

Updating package Step 1 of 2

android update project begins: [C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.bat, update, project, --target, android-19, --path, .]

android update project completed with exit code 0

android update project output:
'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Updated and renamed default.properties to project.properties
Updated local.properties
No project name specified, using Activity name 'MainActivity'.
If you wish to change it, edit the first line of build.xml.
Added file C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\build.xml
Added file C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\proguard-project.txt

Analyzing package Step 2 of 2

build of instrumented project begins...

Using android target= android-19

Building with command line: [C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tools_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107139\tools\ant\bin\ant.bat, -DAPKJAR_DEX=C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\CellStash-dex2jar.jar, -DMTAGENT=C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\libs\monkeytalk-agent.jar, -DERROR_LEVEL=ignore, -DASPECTJ_HOME=C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tools_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107139\tools\AspectJ, -DANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk, -DPROJECT_NAME=CellStash, instrument_apk]

Build completed with exit code -1

Build output:
Buildfile: C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\build.xml

weave_aspects:
     [move] Moving 1 file to C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\libs

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CellStash
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CellStash...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
[gettarget] WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on all Android versions.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\bin\res
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\bin\rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\bin\rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\bin\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\bin\dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CellStash...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\res\values\drawables.xml:3: error: Resource entry action_item_selected is already defined.
     [aapt] res\drawable\action_item_selected.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\res\values\drawables.xml:4: error: Resource entry popup is already defined.
     [aapt] res\drawable\popup.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
     [aapt] C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\res\values-mdpi\drawables.xml:3: error: Resource entry popup_bg is already defined.
     [aapt] res\drawable-mdpi\popup_bg.9.png:0: Originally defined here.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\build_master.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\build_master.xml:698: null returned: 1

Total time: 8 seconds
 : ERROR: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

instrumented APK file was not created at: C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\bin\CellStash-debug.apk

Error instrumenting apk 'C:\Users\dinu\Desktop\EventManagement\CellStash.apk': instrumented APK file was not created at: C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\bin\CellStash-debug.apk

com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.instrumentor.android.AndroidInstrumentor$InstrumentationException: instrumented APK file was not created at: C:\Users\dinu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1397189107138_1\CellStash\bin\CellStash-debug.apk
    at com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.instrumentor.android.AndroidInstrumentor.copyInstrumentedApk(AndroidInstrumentor.java:235)
    at com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.instrumentor.android.AndroidInstrumentor.beginInstrumentation(AndroidInstrumentor.java:199)
    at com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.instrumentor.android.AndroidInstrumentor.instrumentApk(AndroidInstrumentor.java:130)
    at com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.ide.instrumentor.InstrumentApkAction$InstrumentApkJob.run(InstrumentApkAction.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello it seems you are not the only one with this problem, it's related with [Android's pkg-tool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/wiki/9PatchImages) and how it's using a decode function (that double checks for the png raw data)

On cloud monkey's forum you will see these two threads:

[Error instrumenting apk](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/content/error-instrumenting-apk)
[Instrumentation failed](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/content/instrumentation-failed)

I went into [android-apktool's forum](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/issues/detail?id=552) and basically found this

Project Member #1 connor.tumbleson
This would be a feature prevention against bad PNG's. This isn't a bug.
Status: Invalid

So basically it seems you have invalid 9-Path images could you please try using other 9-Patch image instead (just for testing purposes) and corroborate this?